# asp.net routing when using MVC & Web-API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a project with both ASP.NET MVC and Web API in one.

And I have to redirect requests from **/assets/x/y/z.ext**
to
 **/content/assets/x/y/z.ext**

This is the code I wrote:

```
public class AssetsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Assets
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        var url = HttpContext.Request.FilePath;
        return base.Redirect("~/Content" + url);
    }
}
```

And this is the content of App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Assets", "assets/{*url}", new { controller = "Assets", action = "Redirect" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Now for some reason this is not working.
Any help to get this fixed is welcome.

FYI:

- The code was copied from another project where it did work.
- The other project was pure MVC
- I have placed a breakpoint in the Assets controller and it is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Apparently routing does not apply to 'known' file types.
So the resource I was requesting was "http://localhost:8080/assets/images/logo.png" and this did not trigger the assets controller. But "http://localhost:8080/assets/images/logo.png/" did.

So I had to specify that I wanted all files in the assets folder routed.
This is done by adding an extra configuration in the web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

      <add name="AssetsPathContainsFiles" path="/assets/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Remark: It was important to use `path="/assets/*"` and not `path="assets/*"` becuase the second one would also try to handle paths like `"/content/assets/images/logo.png"` while this should be handled by the standard static file handler ... (I assume that the leading slash causes the path to be rooted)

(When I used `path="assets/*"` it caused a loop and the browsers gave me "to many redirect" errors.)